# Can I upgrade Magento 2.3.4 to 2.3.7-p4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

We can't upgrade to 2.4.x as the current theme is not supported however I would like to apply the latest patches. Is the possible to apply security only on an earlier version? Like going from 2.3.4 to 2.3.7-p4 directly or I have to go to 2.3.7 first then apply the security patches? Also would 2.3.7-p4 contain all the previous security fixes released in 2.3.7-p1, 2, 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can go directly on 2.3.7-p4.

Command to upgrade magneto version:

composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.7-p4 --no-update

composer update

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush